# CSS Grid not conforming

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

Red and Blue sections are next to each other but the yellow section is not on the same line and under the blue section, they are also both the same height as the red section, I can not work out where I have gone wrong

```css
.contact-information {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(90px, auto);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-left-section {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: red;
}

.contact-middle-section {
  grid-column: 3/6;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.contact-right-section {
  grid-column: 6/9;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="about light contact-information">
  <div class="contact-left-section">
    <div class="section-title">Phone</div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-middle-section">
    <div class="section-title">Services</div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-right-section">
      <div class="section-title">Email</div>
      <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your `.contact-middle-section` div is never closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you had only defined **eight** columns instead of **nine** but more importantly, you had not closed the `.contact-middle-section` div leaving the layout broken.

```css
.contact-information {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(90px, auto);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-left-section {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: red;
}

.contact-middle-section {
  grid-column: 3/6;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: blue;
}

.contact-right-section {
  grid-column: 6/9;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="about light contact-information">
  <div class="contact-left-section">
    <div class="section-title">Phone</div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-middle-section">
    <div class="section-title">Services</div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="contact-right-section">
    <div class="section-title">Email</div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace:
`grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;`

for:
`grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);`

I hope this solution will help...

Comment: I am finding this odd, when I put                                                                   . grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);    it is the only way it works with the following which is 10                                                                                        contact-left-section{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;}

                               .contact-middle-section{
    grid-column: 4/7;
    grid-row: 1/2;}

                                .contact-right-section{
    grid-column: 7/10;
    grid-row: 1/2;
           background-color: yellow;}